How to dynamically adjust colors depending on the dark mode?
The default header color for DataFrames (render.DataGrid(), render.DataTable()) is a very light grey (probably gainsboro). If I switch an app to dark mode using and DataFrame the header becomes unreadable. Is there any way to make a dict to tell shiny what color to use for the color gainsboro or for a specific object, if I switch to dark mode?
Here's an (not so minimal) MRE:
from shiny import App, render, ui
import polars as pl

app_ui = ui.page_fillable(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.sidebar(ui.input_dark_mode()),
        ui.layout_columns(
            ui.card(
                ui.card_header("card_header1", style='background:gainsboro'),
                ui.output_data_frame("card1"),
                full_screen=True
            ),
            col_widths=12
        )
    )
)

def server(input, output, session):

    @output
    @render.data_frame
    def card1():
        return render.DataGrid(pl.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c','d']}), filters=True)

app = App(app_ui, server)


We can supply an id to the input_dark_mode(), say id="mode". And then we can define css dynamically depending on input.mode() (which is either "light" or "dark") for the required selectors. Below is an example for the card header.
Express
from shiny.express import input, render, ui

with ui.layout_sidebar():
    with ui.sidebar():  
        ui.input_dark_mode(id="mode")
    with ui.layout_columns():
        with ui.card():
            ui.card_header("card_header1", id="card_header1")

@render.ui
def style():
    color = "gainsboro" if input.mode() == "light" else "red"
    css = f"#card_header1 {{ background: {color} }}"
    
    return ui.tags.style(css)

Core
from shiny import App, ui, reactive

app_ui = ui.page_fillable(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.sidebar(ui.input_dark_mode(id="mode")),
        ui.layout_columns(
            ui.card(
                ui.card_header("card_header1", id="card_header1"),
                full_screen=True
            ),
            col_widths=12
        )
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):

    @reactive.effect
    @reactive.event(input.mode)
    def _():
        ui.remove_ui("#header_color")  # Remove any previously added style tag
        
        color = "gainsboro" if input.mode() == "light" else "red"
        css = f"#card_header1 {{ background: {color} }}"

        # Add the CSS to the head of the document
        if css:
            style = ui.tags.style(css, id="#header_color")
            ui.insert_ui(style, selector="head")

app = App(app_ui, server)



Hey, it's you again :). Thanks for that. That works, though I don't know, what that #header_color comes from. Is that because we define it as id for our ui.tags.style element? And how to adjust now the the column header of the dataframe, since this doesn't take an id, does it?

Regarding the first question: #header_color is just an arbitrary id which we use for accessing the (inserted) style chunk. For the column header question: Then you need other css. Generally, the header color is defined by a variable --shiny-datagrid-grid-header-bgcolor and you could use in the above example css = f"shiny-data-frame {{ --shiny-datagrid-grid-header-bgcolor: {color} !important }}" for overwriting it.

Great thanks that worked. How do you know all this? And can I check the default colors somewhere? Right now I just set css for the grid header to '', for light mode an set it only for dark mode, to not change the appearance in light mode. Is also took me a while to see I need the hash in css for #card_header1 vs card_header1 in the id. Ok, last question: what’s that selector='head' doing?

Generally: You are welcome. However, instead of writing thank-you-comments (which should be avoided on SO), if an answer worked for you please really consider voting on it. To the follow-up-questions: They are very broad and I can't go in detail here because this is not an introductory course in web development. I briefly say something to two aspects below.


Default colors: If you are interested in Bootstrap themes and Shiny, then maybe the bslib docs are a good starting point, see e.g. this article on cards. And then you can study the Bootstrap docs. You will then understand what a Sass variable is and where you can check what are the default values and where they are defined.



selector = 'head': <style> tags always have to be included in the <head>. So you insert the style into the head.

